# Creating a transparent viewController in XIB

Tags: iphone

In iPhone how to add a viewControllers view as a subview on top of another viewControllers view, such that the subview should be transparent and whatever components is added to the subview should be visible?

Answer (score 2):

Set the background color of the view to `clearColor`:

```
 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: You can also do this through the xib editor pane by setting the background colour property.

Answer (score 0):

Set background color as "Clear color".